# Calculate minimum Traveled distance from L Latlng in T time

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, geofencing

I want some functionality in my Android/iOS application i.e. **U** user is travelling to **L** location, So when the **U** is 15 minute away from the **L** location he/she will get some Notification.

**What i tried so far:**

1. Calling google API and get travel time from the current location to the **L** location on a particular time interval, when i found it to very close from the 15 minute, i triggered notification to the user(**U**) and stop calling the API.
2. Geo-fence **L** location in such a way that travel time from enter the fence to the **L** location, should be very close to 15 minutes. When user(**U**) enter into the Geo-fence i triggered notification to the user(**U**) and remove the Geo-fence.

But for 1st methods Calling google API is not the right way to achieve that.
In second method the problem is *My locations are not fixed they may vary*. **So the radius of Geo-fence should be different for every location because travel time is different for the location.**

According to to me Geo-fence is a good solution but its dynamic radius are creating the problem.

So is there any other way to achieve that? Or we can fix the dynamic radius issue of Geo-fence in any way?

Comment: "But for 1st methods Calling google API is not the right way to achieve that." Why?

Comment: @sfarbac according to me calling API on particular time interval will cause the network consumption and device resource consumption too,  and what when user not having sufficient data or no data.

Answer (score 0):

For geofence "dynamic radius" you can use workaround like that: set geofence radius to maximum possible, than test user location on `GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER` handler and do what you need only if actual radius less than you need. Something like that:

```
...
// Get the transition type.
int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

// Test that the reported transition was of interest.
if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {
    // start continuously calculate actual radius here
    // actualRadius = calcActualRadius();
    // if (actualRadius < RADIUS_FOR_YOUR_CONDITION) {
    //    // do what you need
    // }  
}
...
```